# textview.settext not working inside spinner Onitemselected event

Tags: android, listview, android-spinner

i have a listview which has a custom layout for its items.
inside this custom layout there is a spinner and i want to change the text of some of the items inside the custom layout based on the spinner selection.
the onItemSelected event is fired just fine,however, textview.settext() functions do  not change the text of textviews.
here is my implementation:
listview_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.28"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_txt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:text="نام دستگاه:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address_txt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:text="آدرس محل نصب:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/diameter_txt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:text="قطر لوله:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/batt1_txt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="میزان باتری1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/batt2_txt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="میزان باتری 2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/last_data_txt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="زمان ارسال آخرین داده:" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sensor_no_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/spin_items"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sensor_type_txt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="نوع سنسور:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sensor_range_txt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="بازه سنسور:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sensor_val_txt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="آخرین داده:" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

listview_adapter:

```
package com.dezelectronic.www.datalogger_abfa;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

class listview_adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<datalogger> data;
    private TextView name,address,diameter,last_time,sensor_type,sensor_range,sensor_lastlog,battery1,battery2;
    private Spinner spin;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public listview_adapter(Context context, List<datalogger> data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
    public  void settxt(String type,String range,String lastlog){
        sensor_type.setText(type);
        sensor_range.setText(range);
        sensor_lastlog.setText(lastlog);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (vi == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_layout, parent,false);
        name =vi.findViewById(R.id.name_txt);
        address =vi.findViewById(R.id.address_txt);
        diameter =vi.findViewById(R.id.diameter_txt);
        spin=vi.findViewById(R.id.sensor_no_spinner);
        last_time=vi.findViewById(R.id.last_data_txt);
        sensor_type=vi.findViewById(R.id.sensor_type_txt);
        sensor_range=vi.findViewById(R.id.sensor_range_txt);
        sensor_lastlog=vi.findViewById(R.id.sensor_val_txt);
        battery1=vi.findViewById(R.id.batt1_txt);
        battery2=vi.findViewById(R.id.batt2_txt);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                switch (pos){
                    case 0:
                        sensor_type.setText("نوع سنسور: "+data.get(position).sensor1_type);
                        sensor_range.setText("بازه سنسور: "+data.get(position).sensor1_range);
                        sensor_lastlog.setText("آخرین داده: "+data.get(position).sensor1_lastlog);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        sensor_type.setText("نوع سنسور:"+data.get(position).sensor2_type);
                        sensor_range.setText("بازه سنسور: "+data.get(position).sensor2_range);
                        sensor_lastlog.setText("آخرین داده: "+data.get(position).sensor2_lastlog);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        sensor_type.setText("نوع سنسور: "+data.get(position).sensor3_type);
                        sensor_range.setText("بازه سنسور: "+data.get(position).sensor3_range);
                        sensor_lastlog.setText("آخرین داده: "+data.get(position).sensor3_lastlog);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        sensor_type.setText("نوع سنسور: "+data.get(position).sensor4_type);
                        sensor_range.setText("بازه سنسور: "+data.get(position).sensor4_range);
                        sensor_lastlog.setText("آخرین داده: "+data.get(position).sensor4_lastlog);
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                sensor_type.setText("نوع سنسور: "+data.get(position).sensor1_type);
                sensor_range.setText("بازه سنسور: "+data.get(position).sensor1_range);
                sensor_lastlog.setText("آخرین داده: "+data.get(position).sensor1_lastlog);
            }
        });

        name.setText("نام دستگاه:"+data.get(position).name);//WORKS FINE
        address.setText("آدرس محل نصب:"+data.get(position).address);//WORKS FINE
        diameter.setText("قطر لوله:"+data.get(position).diameter);//WORKS FINE
        last_time.setText("آخرین داده:"+data.get(position).last_time);//WORKS FINE
        battery1.setText("میزان باتری یک:"+data.get(position).battery1);//WORKS FINE
        battery2.setText("میزان باتری دو:"+data.get(position).battery2);//WORKS FINE
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know waht's return value of pos?may be more than 3 or less than 0, then check it and put it here... or may be data.get(position) equals null, did you check this things before?

Comment: @Farrokh i have verified that pos is either 0,1,2 or 3. I also have verified that data.get(position) is not null(i have printed out the data using a Toast).

Comment: so try this `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: @Farrokh still not working

Comment: tell me that settext work outside of spinner.onitemselected or not?

Comment: @Farrokh it does

Comment: your code has many errors, please put your original code here and your activity code, plz